# Problems with implementing memmove in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, memmove

I am trying to implement the `memmove()` function for a certain quiz, so I dynamically allocated a block of memory with the ptr buffer as temp holder in the swap operation and the swap is done in one loop. When I submit this code it gives me one wrong answer out of 3 test cases. When I separate the swap in two for loops, all cases succeed. So what is the difference  ?

- swap in the **same loop** (One Case Wrong):

  ```
  uint8_t *my_memmove(uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst, size_t length) {
      uint8_t *buffer;
      buffer = (uint8_t*)reserve_words(length);
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          *(buffer+i) = *(src+i);
          *(dst+i) = *(buffer+i);   
      }
      return dst;
      free_words((uint32_t*)buffer);
  }
  ```
- swap in two loops (All Cases Succeed):

  ```
  uint8_t *my_memmove(uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst, size_t length) {
      uint8_t *buffer;
      buffer = (uint8_t*)reserve_words(length);
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          *(buffer+i) = *(src+i);
      }

      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          *(dst+i) = *(buffer+i);   
      }

      return dst;
      free_words((uint32_t*)buffer);
  }
  ```
- reserve_words function used (user_defined) :

  ```
  int32_t *reserve_words(size_t length) {
      int32_t *ptr;
      ptr = (int32_t *)malloc(length * sizeof(int32_t));
      return ptr;
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi, perhaps the memory location is overwritten in the first case before the swap?

Comment: Consider what happens if `src` and `dst` have overlapping regions.

Comment: Note that you leak memory because your `free()` is after your `return`.  You also allocate four times as much memory as necessary because you multiply the length by `sizeof(int32_t)`.  You should check that the memory allocation succeeds before using the allocated memory.

Comment: Why do you have the `reserve_words` function instead of a simple `malloc` call?

Comment: You can't do it in the same loop, that has the same problem as trying the copy directly from source to destination.

Comment: Note that the C11 standard [§7.24.2.2 The `memmove` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.2) says: "Copying takes place _as if_ the n characters from the object pointed to by `s2` are first copied into a temporary array of `n` characters that does not overlap the objects pointed to by `s1` and `s2`, and then the `n` characters from the temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by `s1`."  Only simple-minded implementations do it by an actual double copy.  You can copy head-to-tail if the areas don't overlap or `s1` < `s2`, and tail-to-head otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There's no portable way to tell if they overlap, because you can't compare pointers between different arrays. The real implementation of `memmove()` isn't limited like this.

Comment: Note `reserve_words()` allocates excess memory.  Suggest `ptr = malloc((length+3)/4 * sizeof *ptr);` or the like.

Comment: @Barmar — yes, and that's why the standard goes through the shenanigans with the spare memory, but a library for a particular implementation can know whether you can portably compare pointers despite the restrictions the standard has, and can therefore make that determination. That's why it is a standard library function — the standard library is tailored to a particular implementation.  On most machines, you can make that comparison — possibly by converting addresses to `uintptr_t` values — but it is not guaranteed by the standard to be portable (but the implementation knows that it is safe).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right, but since he's trying to implement his own `memmove`, and presumably it should be portable, none of that helps him.

Comment: @Barmar — It depends on what the rules of engagement are.  There's nothing in the question that says it must be portable.  However, the relevant points have now been made.  Simple minded but portable code will work somewhat as shown; efficient code will not.

Comment: @Barmar: equality checking is well defined between any two objects of the same type, and that's sufficient to check for overlap (if you do it in a loop). Of course, the loop is inefficient, but it's less work than an unnecessary copy, and there's an off-chance that the compiler will figure it out.

Comment: @rici I realized that, but I didn't think anyone could be seriously suggesting equality checking between all the array elements.

Comment: @Barmar: If you're prepared to malloc an temporary buffer and copy to it, then the equality checking is entirely reasonable. (You only have to know if the last byte in src is somewhere in dst, so it's O(n). If the overlap goes the other way, it's still safe to do the copy left to right.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that memmove is guaranteed to work with overlapping memory blocks. If you want to see a case where your first version would fail, try this:

```
char str[20]="Hello, World!";
my_memmove(&str[0], &str[1], 13);
puts(str);
```

The output is:

```
HHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

It's easy to realize why. Every iteration you will write to the byte you're going to read from next iteration.

So your first version of `my_memmove` should really be called `my_memcpy` instead, because `memcpy` is not guaranteed to work with overlapping memory areas, which `memmove` is.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, just noticed but thanks

Comment: This only applies to the version with one loop.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but that was OP:s question, right? OP wonders why the first version fails and the second don't.

Answer (score 1):

- The first version copies from the source to the destination as it copies to the temporary array: if the source and destination arrays overlap and `src < dst` you will overwrite parts of the source array before copying them. This is exactly where the difficulty lies when implementing `memmove()`
- The second version allocated a temporary array, copies from the source to it, then copies from the temporary array to destination: no problem, except you `free` the temporary array after the `return` statement, so there is a memory leak, and you are probably not expected to allocate memory for this assignment.
- There is a bug in all copying loops: `i` should be defined as a `size_t`, not a `uint8_t`. As coded, the function will fail for blocks longer than 255 bytes.
- there is no need to allocate `length` words to save `length` bytes.

The trick for `memmove()` is to test whether `dst` points inside the source array and copy from the end of the source array to the beginning if such is the case. There is no fully portable way to do this, but for most current systems with a flat address space, the test `if (dst > src && dst < src + length)` works fine.

Here is a simplistic implementation (note that your prototype has the `src` and `dst` pointers transposed from the standard `memmove()` function):

```c
uint8_t *my_memmove(const uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst, size_t length) {
    if (dst > src && dst < src + length) {
        for (size_t i = length; i-- > 0;)
            dst[i] = src[i];
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
            dst[i] = src[i];
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: in memmove use of `const` is disputable

Comment: @P__J__: Why is that? `src` is not used to write to the source array, hence a `const` qualified pointer can be passed to `memmove` and the corresponding argument must be `const`-qualified too. The fact that the source and destination arrays can overlap means `src` an `dst` cannot be `restrict` qualified, which is a different matter.

Comment: As I wrote disputable. IMO if there is any potential path of execution which writes this oblect it should not be declared as `const`. `restrict` is a different issue

Comment: @P__J__: if `memmove` writes the object though the `src` pointer, I agree. If memory modified through the `dst` pointer happens to overlap memory read through the `src` pointer, it is not a reason to `const` qualify `*src`, but it is the very reason to not `restrict` qualify either pointer, contrary to `memcpy` where the requirement is that these areas be disjoint. The specification for `restrict` is not perfect but applies precisely to the case in question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Memory leak

```
    return dst;
    free_words((uint32_t*)buffer);
```

You will never call `free_words` as it will return earlier.

2. When you copy in one loop and memory locations overlap your algorithm will overwrite the data and the function will not work.
3. This buffer completelly useless and it is an example of bad programming
4. function should get and return `void *` pointers.
5. You do not have to cast the pointers if one side of the assignment is (void *)

```
void *mymemmove(void *dest, void *src, size_t size)
{
    void *saveddest = dest;
    unsigned char *ucdest = dest, *ucsrc = src;
    if(dest && src && size)
    {
        if(dest < src)
        {
            while(size--)
            {
                *ucdest++ = *ucsrc++;
            }
        }
        else if(src < dest) //this if to avoid copy if dest == src (not needed)
        {
            ucdest += size - 1; ucsrc += size - 1;
            while(size--)
            {
                *ucdest-- = *ucsrc--;
            }
        }
    }
    return saveddest;
}
```

Comment: Reasonable, yet `dest < src` is UB.  Good use of `unsigned char *`.  Maybe `void *src` --> `const void *src`?

Comment: @chux generally yes, but it will work on **every** arcvhitecture OP may use.